# Better use of rounded corners with tikz on \draw[->]

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8


\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\multilinks}[3]{\foreach \noeud in {#1} {\draw[<-, rounded corners] (#2.west) -| ++(-#3em,0em) |- (\noeud.east);}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \centering
        \tikzset{
            basic/.style={draw, rounded corners=2pt, thick, text width=8em, align=flush center, node distance=2em},
        }
        \begin{tikzpicture}[]
            \matrix[row sep=2em, column sep=4em, every node/.style={basic}] {
                \node(n1){Text}; & \node(n3){another text}; \\
                \node(n2){one thing}; & \node(n4){again text}; \\
            };
            \multilinks{n1,n2}{n3}{3}
            \multilinks{n1}{n4}{1}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It gives me this result:

[image]

As you can see, a curve is weird. How can I fix it?

Here's the result I want:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slight change in the definition of `\multilinks` and the list `#1` in the first `\multilinks`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\newcommand{\multilinks}[3]{
    \foreach \noeud in {#1} {
        \draw[<-, rounded corners] (#2.west) -- ++(-#3 em,0em) |- (\noeud.east);
    }
}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    basic/.style={
        draw, 
        rounded corners=2pt, 
        thick, 
        text width=8em, 
        align=flush center, 
        node distance=2em
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\fontsize{8}{9} \selectfont
\matrix[row sep=2em, column sep=4em, every node/.style={basic}] {
    \node(n1){Text}; & \node(n3){another text}; \\
    \node(n2){one thing}; & \node(n4){again text}; \\
};
\multilinks{n2}{n3}{3}
\multilinks{n1}{n4}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

#### Edit

In case you want to keep the original way, the definition of `\multilinks` is a bit more complicated:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\newcommand{\multilinks}[3]{
    \begin{scope}[x=1em,y=1em]
    \newdimen\xend
    \newdimen\yend  
    \path (#2.west);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\xend}{\yend}
    \foreach \i in {#1} {
        \newdimen\xstart
        \newdimen\ystart 
        \path (\i.east);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\xstart}{\ystart}
        \coordinate (1) at ({\xend-#3 em},\ystart);
        \coordinate (2) at ({\xend-#3 em},\yend);
        \ifdim\ystart=\yend
            \draw[->] (\i.east)--(#2.west);
        \else
            \draw[->,rounded corners] (\i.east)--(1)--(2)--(#2.west);
        \fi
    }
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    basic/.style={
        draw, 
        rounded corners=2pt, 
        thick, 
        text width=8em, 
        align=flush center, 
        node distance=2em
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\fontsize{8}{9} \selectfont
\matrix[row sep=2em, column sep=4em, every node/.style={basic}] {
    \node(n1){Text}; & \node(n3){another text}; \\
    \node(n2){one thing}; & \node(n4){again text}; \\
};
\multilinks{n1,n2}{n3}{3}
\multilinks{n1}{n4}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

We have to add an `\ifdim` because Ti*k*Z is quite confused when it is commanded to draw a `rounded corners` path from point *A* to point *A* (i.e. two identical points):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.2cm]
\draw[rounded corners] (0,0) --(1,0) --(1,0)--(2,0) ; % Some bugs?
\draw[rounded corners] (0,-1)--(1,-1)--       (2,-1);
\draw[rounded corners] (0,-2)--               (2,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't works with ``\multilinks{n1,n2}{n3}{3}``

Comment: @Vinccool96 I edited my answer so that it works with `\multilinks{n1,n2}{n3}{3}`.